# How to resolve the following error message: Should have subtitle controller already set

Tags: audio, subtitle

I have an App that should play small sound files, and I get no error at the compilation state and the application runs successfully, but, unfortunately, it doesn't launch the sound.

At the same time I open the `Logcat` and see the following error message:

> E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set

How can this be resolved?